# My code is checking only 1 if condition in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def check(str):
    if(str.isalnum())==True:
        return True
    if(str.isalpha())==True:
        return True
    if(str.isdigit())==True:
        return True
    if(str.islower())==True:
        return True
    if(str.isupper())==True:
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    if(check(s)):
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

It is showing only one condition's result. For example, if I type `qA2` it is showing one `True` instead of

```
True
True
True
True
True
```

Comment: @engineero a better close would be to find the dupe IMO and close with that instead of a custom reason

Comment: Minor stylistic point: in most languages, there's no reason to explicitly compare to `true` and `false`.

Comment: @Austin not so sure. I'm on a phone so it's tough to search properly. Touches on the issue but I think there's a canonical. I just can't think of it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are "returning" from the function if one of the `if` conditions evaluates to true.

You can read more about the keyword `return` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement). 
The gist is, as the word says, it "returns" from the function with specified value(s).

If you want the other if conditions to get evaluated too, you will need to maintain a small data structure of all successful `if` conditions, eg:

```
def check(str):
    # let's initialise a dictionary with all False values.
    # If any if condition turns True, then we will set 
    # that value to True in the dictionary.
    res = {
        "isalnum":False,
        "isalpha":False,
        "isdigit":False,
        "islower":False,
        "isupper":False,
    }

    if(str.isalnum())==True:
        res["isalnum"] = True
    if(str.isalpha())==True:
        res["isalpha"] = True
    if(str.isdigit())==True:
        res["isdigit"] = True
    if(str.islower())==True:
        res["islower"] = True
    if(str.isupper())==True:
        res["isupper"] = True

    return res # This returns a dictionary with all values
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    if(check(s)):
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping

Answer (score 0):

`return` leaves the function immediately. The first condition which succeeds will cause the rest to be skipped, the way you defined your function.

If you want to check all the conditions every time, try something like

```py
def check(str):
    whether = True
    if not str.isalnum():
        whether = False
    if not str.isalpha():
        whether = False
    if not str.isdigit():
        whether = False
    if not str.islower():
        whether = False
    if not str.isupper():
        whether = False
    return whether
```

Printing something in each branch seems excessive, but could certainly be added.

Answer (score 0):

`return` stops the function's execution. Nothing after a return statement will be run, and a function can only have a single return value. If you want to see the result for *all* conditions, store them in a `List` or a `Dict` and return that instead, for example:

```
def check(str):
    results = {}
    results['isalnum'] = str.isalnum()
    results['isalpha'] = str.isalpha()
    results['isdigit'] = str.isdigit()
    results['islower'] = str.islower()
    results['isupper'] = str.isupper()
    return results
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping